# Unable to Create Jasmine Concurrent Grunt Task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-concurrent

I have set up a bunch of taks that all work but I am having trouble configuring my tests task. I have Jasmine-node up and running and I am able to run my tests from the command line, but I can't seem to get the grunt task working.

GruntFile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        jitGrunt: true
    });

};
```

aliases.yaml: (shortened to show only the test task)

```
test:
    - 'concurrent:test'
```

test.js

```
module.exports = {
    jasmine: {
        all: {
            src: '.',
            options: {
                specs: ['../tests/sms/textReceiver-spec.js']
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Folder Structure:

- grunt

  - concurrent.js
  - test.js
  - etc
- GruntFile.js
- tests

  - sms

    - textReceiver-spec.js

The task loads but it just sits there, and nothing happens. No further information, not even an error. It makes me think it's just not finding my test files? But I've tried linking to a file directly, with the same result.

Result:

ben_cripps$ grunt test

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task

but that's it

Comment: What's the output if you run with the verbose (`--verbose`) flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine). According to their documentation, the `src` property is used like this (like everywhere else, with wildcards):

```
src: 'src/**/*.js'
```

But you are using it like this:

```
src: '.'
```